# How to show only 2 annotations

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I have a huge annotations list. How can i show only two specific annotations? for example i want by default to be checked only and show annotations for "Restaurants" and "Bars". If the user wants to display more then from the action bar menu from Google Maps will check others.

```
ar args = arguments[0] || {};
$.winTitle.text = args.title;
$.win.addEventListener('open', function(e) {

    if (OS_ANDROID) {

        var ab = $.win.activity.actionBar;

        ab.title = args.title;

    }

});

var rows = [];
var checkedRows = [];

var categories = [];

var items = [];

var defaultState = "true";

var MapModule = require('ti.map');

rows.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title : L('checkAll'),
    color : "#737373",
    rightImage : '',
    font:{
        fontWeight: 'bold'
   },
    height : 60,
    checked : 'false',
    left : 10

}));

for (var prop in args.data ) {
    args.data[prop].checked = defaultState;
    rows.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title : prop,
        color : "#737373",
        rightImage : OS_ANDROID ? '/images/icons/check.png' : '/icons/check.png',
        height : 60,
        left : 10

    }));
};

$.menu.data = rows;

var isOpen = false;
function onBlankTouch(e) {
    $.popup.animate({
        left : 1500,
        duration : 250
    }, function() {
        isOpen = false;
    });
}

function openMenu(e) {
    $.popup.animate({
        left : isOpen ? 1500 : 0,
        duration : 250
    }, function() {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
    });
}

function onHomeIconClick() {
    $.win.close();
}

function onWindowOpened(e) {
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        var activity = $.win.activity;
        activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
            e.menu.clear();

            e.menu.add({
                icon : '/images/icons/menu.png',
                showAsAction : Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            }).addEventListener('click', openMenu);
        };

        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    var timeout;
    $.mapview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (OS_IOS) {
            if (e.clicksource === 'annotation')
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (e.clicksource && (e.clicksource === 'pin' || e.clicksource.indexOf('infoWindow', 'title') > -1)) {
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    for (var i = 0,
                        j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
                        var item = items[i];
                        if (item.name === e.title) {
                            Ti.App.fireEvent(PW.E.OPEN, {
                                category : {
                                    id : item.id,
                                    type : 'itemId',
                                    data : item
                                },
                                title : item.name
                            });
                            return;
                        }
                    };
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
         else {
            if (e.clicksource && (e.clicksource === 'rightPane' || e.clicksource.indexOf('infoWindow', 'title') > -1)) {
                for (var i = 0,
                    j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var item = items[i];
                    if (item.name === e.title) {
                        Ti.App.fireEvent(PW.E.OPEN, {
                            category : {
                                id : item.id,
                                type : 'itemId',
                                data : item
                            },
                            title : item.name
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                };

            }
        }

    });

    annotations();
}

function annotations(title) {
    $.mapview.removeAllAnnotations();
    items = [];
    var ann = [];
    var currentColor = 0;
    for (var prop in args.data ) {
        if (args.data[prop].checked=="false") {
            var color = ++currentColor;
            if (color > 2) {
                color = currentColor = 0;
            }
            for (var i = 0, j = args.data[prop].items.length; i < j; i++) {
                var it = args.data[prop].items[i];
                items.push(it);
                ann.push(MapModule.createAnnotation({
                    latitude : parseFloat(it.lat_long[0]),
                    longitude : parseFloat(it.lat_long[1]),
                    title : it.name,
                    canShowCallout : false,
                    rightButton : OS_ANDROID ? '/images/arrow.png' : '/icons/arrow.png',
                    item : it.name,
                    pincolor : color
                }));
            };
        }
    }

    if (ann.length > 0)
        $.mapview.addAnnotations(ann);
    $.mapview.setLocation({
        latitude : 37.9908997,
        longitude : 23.7033199,
        animate : true,
        latitudeDelta : 7.50,
        longitudeDelta : 7.50
    });
}

function menuClick(e) {

    console.log(e.row.title);
    console.log(e.rowData.title);
    if (e.row.title == L('checkAll')) {
        if (e.row.checked == "true") {

            e.row.rightImage = '';
            e.row.checked = "false";
        } else {

            e.row.rightImage = OS_ANDROID ? '/images/icons/check.png' : '/icons/check.png';
            e.row.checked = "true";

            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rows[i].rightImage = '';
                args.data[rows[i].title].checked = "false";

            }
            $.mapview.removeAllAnnotations();

        }
    } else {


        if (args.data[e.row.title].checked == "false") {
            args.data[e.row.title].checked = "true";
            e.row.rightImage = '';

        } else {
            args.data[e.row.title].checked = "false";
            e.row.rightImage = OS_ANDROID ? '/images/icons/check.png' : '/icons/check.png';

        }

        annotations();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to handle that logic yourself. Add this to where you loop over the items and then decide if you need to add them depending on boolean properties. Then when the users changes filters, change these booleans and rerender.